# Pandas -- String of boolean conditions -- SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am wondering if anyone can assist me with this warning I get in my code. The code DOES score items correctly, but this warning is bugging me and I can't seem to find a good fix, given that I need to string a few boolean conditions together.

Background: Imagine that I have a magical fruit identifier and I have a csv file that lists what fruit was identified and in which area (1, 2, etc.). I read in the csv file with columns of "FruitID" and "Area." An identification of "APPLE" or "apple" in Zone 1 is scored as correct/true (other identified fruits are incorrect/false). I apply similar logic for other areas, but I won't get into that.

Any ideas for how to correct this? Should I use `.loc`, although I'm not sure that this will work with multiple booleans. Thanks!

My code snippet that initiates the CopyWarning:

```
Area1_ID_df['Area 1, Score']=(Area1_ID_df['FruitID']=='APPLE')|(Area1_ID_df['FruitID']=='apple')
```

Stacktrace:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas finds it ambiguous what you are trying to do. Certain operations return a view of the dataset, whereas other operations make a copy of the dataset. The confusion is whether you want to modify a copy of the dataset or whether you want to modify the original dataset or are trying to create something new.

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/ is a great link to learn more about the problem you are having.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the line that's causing this error is truly: `s = t | u`, where `t` and `u` are Boolean series indexed consistently, you should not worry about `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

This is a **warning** rather than an **error**. The latter indicates there is a problem, the former indicates there *may* be a problem. In this case, Pandas guesses you may be working with a copy rather than a view.

If the result is as you expect, you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Funny thing is the code is tallying things correctly. I'll continue to keep an eye on things and cautiously ignore the warning. :)